# Slack Application : how to manage bot connections to different teams?

Tags: slack-api, slack

I'm trying to build a Slack application using a bot to interact with users.

I would like to distribute this app in the Slack app directory. I have to get an oauth authorisation token for each team, which I store in my database.

The thing is **I am not sure I really understand how I am supposed to manage the SlackClient's connection to each team**. Let me explain how I see things at the moment.

- I can authorise my app to access and publish stuff in different teams by getting an authorisation token with the Slack button. This gives me an access token and bot_token for each enabled team.
- To post in a team, I am supposed to connect the SlackClient to this specific team using these generated tokens right ? So **is my app supposed to disconnect/reconnect my SlackClient each time it receives a request from a different team** ? Or can a SlackClient connect to several teams at the same time ?

I followed this tutorial to make things work at first, but it doesn't really explain how to manage different teams connection I think (https://github.com/slackapi/Slack-Python-Onboarding-Tutorial).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No. Connections are managed by the web server on which your slackclient is running. So you don't have to deal with them. You bot only needs to react individually to each event request he will receive from Slack. Everything else is managed by the web server.(*)

Here is how it works in detail:

The bot you mentioned is using Slack's [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api) to communicate with the Slack teams. After the bot is installed for a team Slack start sending event requests to your bot whenever the event your subscribed to occurred. e.g. if you subscribed to [message events](https://api.slack.com/events/message) your bot will get a request for each message that is send in all channels your bot is invited to.

The event request from Slack contains the team ID of the team, so you bot just needs to pick the corresponding access token from his database and its reply (e.g. sending a message using the chosen token) will go to the correct team. In case of message events the event request will also contain the channel and user ID, so your bot can send his reply to the correct channel and user.

Here is an example of how the event request from Slack looks like: (from the official documentation)

```
{
        "token": "z26uFbvR1xHJEdHE1OQiO6t8",
        "team_id": "T061EG9RZ",
        "api_app_id": "A0FFV41KK",
        "event": {
                "type": "reaction_added",
                "user": "U061F1EUR",
                "item": {
                        "type": "message",
                        "channel": "C061EG9SL",
                        "ts": "1464196127.000002"
                },
                "reaction": "slightly_smiling_face"
        },
        "event_ts": "1465244570.336841",
        "type": "event_callback",
        "authed_users": [
                "U061F7AUR"
        ]
}
```

(*) Technically the web server will spawn multiple instances of your bot to deal with multiple parallel event requests.

Comment: Things are starting to get clearer. But at what time am I supposed to input the corresponding token when making an API call, for example to post a message... :  `self.client.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel=message_obj.channel, username=name, icon_emoji=self.emoji, text=attachments)`